# File browse on Android App

Tags: java, android, cordova

I want to create an Android app. There will be a form  which will allow users to choose files using  html tag. There will also be a submit button on the form, onclick of which the chosen file should get copied from the Android device to a location on the server.

Right now the form is on an html page and I have been using phonegap for the development.

As of now, I have created a plugin which reads the file from sdcard folder and using a jsch library I am uploading the files on the sftp server.

While researching, I found that many people are using the following method:
The form details are posted to the server and using a php script the file content are read using $_FILES (but I do not want to follow this approach)

I need a way, so that when the user chooses the file using browse option this file name will be picked up when the form is posted.

for  e.g   below is the code for MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.filepicker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends /* Activity */DroidGap {


    private Object request;


    // @Override
    // protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity");

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }


    public void onFormSubmit() {
       //this  method is to be invoked when the user clicks form submit button

       Log.i("Custom Function Called", "Custom Function Called");


    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>              
<head>          
<title>XXXX | INDEX</title>                     
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/toast.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/FileUploadPlugin.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/media-query.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magnific-popup.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">             

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('device is ready');

    var fileupload1 = new FileUploadPlugin();
         var ipaddress = "xxxxxxx";       
         var userId ="xxx";
         var password = "xxx";

    /*cordova.exec(onFileSystemSuccess, fail, "FileUploadPlugin", "echo",
     [ipaddress,userId,password]); */

  /*cordova.exec(onFileSystemSuccess, fail, "FileUploadPlugin", "display",
     ["DEF"]);   */
    /* callNewActivity();*/

     alert('after execution is called');

 }

    function onFileSystemSuccess(result) {
    alert('on success'+result);
   // alert('msg'+msg);
    // alert('on status'+status); 
   console.log('this is success');
  /*     console.log(result); */


       /* console.log(fileSystem.name);
        console.log(fileSystem.root.name);*/
    }

    function fail(error) {
     alert('on failure'+error);
     console.log('this is error');
    alert('err code'+evt.target.error.code);
    /*    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        */
    }

     function onFormSubmit() {
        window.MainActivity.onFormSubmit();
    }



</script>                                                                                                                                                   
</head>                                                                     
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Attach File</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="file-attachment-form" action="http://PutYourServerURL">
           <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="data">Put some text:</label>
                <input name="data" type="text" id="data"/>
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="attachment">Attachment:</label>
                <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment"/>
            </div> 

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#file-attachment-form').submit(function () {
            formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            alert('new '+formData);
/*console.log(formData);*/
          /*  $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:$('#file-attachment-form').attr('action'),
                data:formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Failed to upload file')
                },
                success:function () {
                    alert('File uploaded')
                }
            })*/
            /*alert('formData = '+formData);*/
            onFormSubmit();



        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

e.g MainActivity.java file will have  a function called "onFormSubmit" this function should be able to read the files parameter.

I would like to know if this is a possible method. If not then any pointer/suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Many things unclear to me: `There will be a submit button on the form` ? On which form? Where is a form? You didn't tell that there was a form to begin with. You also did not tell what the connection would be between your form and MainActivity. Why thanks in advance as you are expected to express thanks after beeing helped?

Comment: @greenapps.. I have edited the question now. Hope that makes it clear for you..

Comment: Are you using a WebView to load that html file from assets? We can only see if what you want is possible if you post the html source and the javascript interface code.

Comment: @greenapps: I have added the html file... Yes, I am using Webview to load that html file

Comment: Ok. Now is onFormSubmit() called at the moment? Does the javascript interface work? Are you able/permitted to adapt the html source when needed?

Comment: I am new to android development.. So I am unable to understand How the onFormSubmit would be able to read the posted parameters...

Comment: That i know already from the start. But please answer my questions.

Comment: Yes onFormSubmit function in MainActivity.java gets called when the "Submit" button is clicked. Yes the javascript interface works... Did not get what you meant by "Are you able/permitted to adapt the html source when needed?"

Comment: If some javascript had to be added in order for all to work, then are you allowed/able to add it to the html file?

Comment: yes... i am allowed to add the javascript to the html file.

Comment: Ok. Then lets start. You will know about input validation of form input fields. Mostly done by javascript. The javascript can display alerts and return true/false. Upon false the form will not be submitted. You have already somewhere such code? This javascript reads the name of each input field and can read the values too. You have to add such type of script. And all your input fields must have good names/id's. As you have a javascript interface you can extract the name of the file with javascript and transfer to main activity.

Comment: So you will manage now?

Comment: Can you make this statement clear "As you have a javascript interface you can extract the name of the file with javascript and transfer to main activity.". Will the main activity be able to locate the location of the file with just the file name e.g "sdcard/storage/test.txt"?

Comment: It will probably then be "/sdcard/storage/test.txt". If it is like this then yes of course. To be honest I did this with a lot of input type fields but never with a file chooser for file upload. So I actually don't know what absolute/relative path there would be you would get. A small test would reveil it. Please report here.

Comment: I want to be able to trace any path location the user will pick the file from... I wanted the filepath to be determined at the runtime and not hardcoded in the code... I am not sure whether that is possible to trace

Comment: Of course not hardcoded as you don't know what the user will choose. Please find out if the filename is relative or absolute.